# Querying Azure app insights from an Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, appinsights

I have an Azure Function instance. I would like to execute a KQL query to fetch some data from an Azure app insights instance of another app, then push the data to an on-prem database.

I am aware that we can send a `GET` request to the REST endpoint of the app insights via an API token, but is there a better way to do this? Ideally, I would like to directly execute the query somehow, since my Azure function resides in the same resource group.

Comment: But how easy do you expect it to be?  There's always going to be an SDK or something you'd need to use to get the data.  "I would like to directly execute the query somehow ..." and you have that through the REST endpoint.

Comment: @Skin I was just wondering if there was a direct integration of some sort. Right now, I send the GET request, parse the data, transform it, etc.

Comment: I can only think of this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Monitor.Query/